# How to find $\int_0^1 x^4(1-x)^5dx$ quickly?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

*This question came in the Rajshahi University admission exam 2018-19*

Q) $\int_0^1 x^4(1-x)^5dx$=?

(a) $\frac{1}{1260}$

(b) $\frac{1}{280}$

(c)$\frac{1}{315}$

(d) None

[This is a big integral (click on show steps)](https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=x%5E4%281-x%29%5E5&lbound=0&ubound=1):

$$\left[-\dfrac{\left(x-1\right)^6\left(126x^4+56x^3+21x^2+6x+1\right)}{1260}\right]_0^1=\frac{1}{1260}$$

It takes a lot of time to compute. How can I compute this quickly (30 seconds) using a shortcut?

Comment: Since this is from a university admission exam, are we to assume that this can be done quickly (30 seconds) using only high school math?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use Beta function:
$$
B(a,b)=\int_0^1x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}\mathrm dx={\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)\over\Gamma(a+b)}.
$$
Since $\Gamma(a)=(a-1)!$ when $a$ is a positive integer, we have
$$
\int_0^1x^4(1-x)^5\mathrm dx=B(5,6)={\Gamma(5)\Gamma(6)\over\Gamma(11)}={4!\dot5!\over10!}={4\cdot3\cdot2\over10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6}={1\over1260}.
$$

Comment: I've found a shorter way:

$$\int_0^1x^{p}(1-x)^{q}\mathrm dx=\frac{p!\cdot q!}{(p+q+1)!}$$

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic Well, this method is essentially equivalent to what I did.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't have the beta function formula memorized, you can use integration by parts repeatedly
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}x^4(1-x)^5\,dx &= \left[x^4 \cdot -\dfrac{1}{6}(1-x)^6\right]_{0}^{1} - \int_{0}^{1}4x^3 \cdot -\dfrac{1}{6}(1-x)^6\,dx
\\
&= \dfrac{4}{6}\int_{0}^{1}x^3(1-x)^6\,dx
\\
&= \dfrac{4}{6}\left[x^3 \cdot -\dfrac{1}{7}(1-x)^7\right]_{0}^{1} - \dfrac{4}{6}\int_{0}^{1}3x^2 \cdot -\dfrac{1}{7}(1-x)^7\,dx
\\
&= \dfrac{4 \cdot 3}{6 \cdot 7}\int_{0}^{1}x^2(1-x)^7\,dx
\\
&= \dfrac{4 \cdot 3}{6 \cdot 7}\left[x^2 \cdot -\dfrac{1}{8}(1-x)^8\right]_{0}^{1} - \dfrac{4 \cdot 3}{6 \cdot 7}\int_{0}^{1}2x \cdot -\dfrac{1}{8}(1-x)^8\,dx
\\
&= \dfrac{4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2}{6 \cdot 7 \cdot 8}\int_{0}^{1}x(1-x)^8\,dx
\\
&= \dfrac{4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2}{6 \cdot 7 \cdot 8}\left[x \cdot -\dfrac{1}{9}(1-x)^9\right]_{0}^{1} - \dfrac{4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2}{6 \cdot 7 \cdot 8}\int_{0}^{1}1 \cdot -\dfrac{1}{9}(1-x)^9\,dx
\\
&= \dfrac{4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2}{6 \cdot 7 \cdot 8 \cdot 9}\int_{0}^{1}(1-x)^9\,dx
\\
&= \dfrac{4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2}{6 \cdot 7 \cdot 8 \cdot 9}\left[-\dfrac{1}{10}(1-x)^{10}\right]_{0}^{1}
\\
&= \dfrac{4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2}{6 \cdot 7 \cdot 8 \cdot 9 \cdot 10}
\\
&= \dfrac{1}{1260}
\end{align*}

This looks fairly long since I wrote out all the steps in detail. However, if you notice the pattern, you can probably arrive at the answer faster. Also, if are familiar with the [Tabular Integration Method](https://brilliant.org/wiki/tabular-integration/), then you only need to do a fairly short amount of scratchwork.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it is not the fastest way to solve it, but it is faster than computing the original integral:

\begin{align*}
I = \int_{0}^{1}x^{4}(1 - x)^{5}\mathrm{d}x = \int_{0}^{1}(1 - x)^{4}x^{5}\mathrm{d}x & \Rightarrow 2I = \int_{0}^{1}x^{4}(1-x)^{4}(x + (1 - x))\mathrm{d}x\\\\
& \Rightarrow 2I = \int_{0}^{1}x^{4}(1-x)^{4}\mathrm{d}x\\\\
& \Rightarrow 2I = \int_{0}^{1}x^{4}(1 - 4x + 6x^{2} - 4x^{3} + x^{4})\mathrm{d}x\\\\
& \Rightarrow 2I = \int_{0}^{1}(x^{4} - 4x^{5} + 6x^{6} - 4x^{7} + x^{8})\mathrm{d}x\\\\
& \Rightarrow 2I = \frac{1}{5} - \frac{2}{3} + \frac{6}{7} - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{9}\\\\
& \Rightarrow I = \frac{1}{1260}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

$$I=\int_{0}^{1}x^4(1-x)^5 dx$$
Let $x=\sin^2 t$ then
$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} 2 \sin^9 t \cos^{11} t dt$$
Use Beta integral
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin^{x}t \cos^{y}t dt=\frac{1}{2} \frac{\Gamma((x+1)/2)\Gamma((y+1)/2)}{\Gamma((x+y+2)/2)}$$
to get
$$I=\frac{\Gamma(5)\Gamma(6)}{\Gamma(11)}=\frac{4! 5!}{10!}=\frac{1}{1260}$$

Answer (score 3):

Personally I'm somewhat inclined to use the fifth row of Pascal's triangle: $$  
                 1\\
                1\quad 1 \\
               1\quad  2\quad 1\\
              1\quad  3\quad 3\quad 1\\
            1 \quad 4\quad  6\quad  4 \quad 1\\
            1\quad  5\quad  10\quad 10\quad 5 \quad 1$$

Thus $$(1-x)^5=1-5x^1+10x^2-10x^3+5x^4-x^5$$.

So, $$x^4-5x^5+10x^6-10x^7+5x^8-x^9$$ is the integrand.

We get $$ 1/5-5/6+10/7-10/8+5/9-1/10=-19/30+10/56+41/90=-16/90+10/56=-8/45+5/28=1/1260$$.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say this method helps you in solving it in 30 seconds, but I think it can help you in simplifying the calculations so that the integral can be computed faster

First consider by usage of the Binomial Theorem

$$(1-x)^5=\sum_{k=0}^{5}\binom{5}{k}(1)^k(-x)^{5-k}=\sum_{k=0}^{5}\binom{5}{k}(-1)^{5-k}(x)^{5-k}$$

from which you can get by multiplying by $x^4$

$$x^4(1-x)^5=\sum_{k=0}^{5}\binom{5}{k}(-1)^{5-k}(x)^{9-k}$$

applying the integral to the sum

$$\int_{0}^{1}x^4(1-x)^5\cdot dx=\sum_{k=0}^{5}\binom{5}{k}(-1)^{5-k}\bigg(\frac{x^{10-k}}{10-k} \bigg)_{0}^{1}$$

which will give

$$\int_{0}^{1}x^4(1-x)^5\cdot dx=\sum_{k=0}^{5}\binom{5}{k}(-1)^{5-k}\bigg(\frac{1}{10-k} \bigg)$$

Expanding the sum gives

$$-\binom{5}{0}\bigg(\frac{1}{10}\bigg)+\binom{5}{1}\bigg(\frac{1}{9}\bigg)-\binom{5}{2}\bigg(\frac{1}{8} \bigg)+\binom{5}{3}\bigg(\frac{1}{7}\bigg)-\binom{5}{4}\bigg(\frac{1}{6} \bigg)+\binom{5}{5}\bigg(\frac{1}{5} \bigg)$$

simplifying will give

$$\frac{-1}{10} +\frac{5}{9} -\frac{10}{8} +\frac{10}{7} -\frac{5}{6} +\frac{1}{5}=\frac{1}{1260}$$

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}x^4(1-x)^5\,dx
&=\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}(1/2+x)^4(1/2-x)^5\,dx\\
&=\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}(1/4-x^2)^4(1/2-x)\,dx\\
&=\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}(1/4-x^2)^4(1/2)\,dx\\
&\qquad+\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}(1/4-x^2)^4(-x)\,dx\\
&=\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}(1/4-x^2)^4(1/2)\,dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{1/2}(1/4-x^2)^4\,dx,
\end{align}$$
which is easily computed to $1/1260$.

Comment: To compute the last integral, do you expand $(1/4-x^2)^4$, then integrate term by term, then let $x=1/2$? If so, then wouldn't it be easier to just take the original integral, expand $x^4(1-x)^5$, then integrate term by term, then let $x=1$?

Comment: This is more or less the way that I tried to do this problem. After several tries I realised that the last integral is not any easier to do than the initial integral. You have almost the same number of terms and the same muddle of fractions at the end, with added halves in the mix. Initially I actually thought the problem said $1/1280$ so I was looking for an easy "powers of two" answer.